# why do i need to use strtotime() to use date() with mysql

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this code successfully, but is there a way to run this where I don't need to convert my variable from a string to a number?

I am confused and wondering if I am doing it efficiently because the mysql timestamp datatype is a string but the php timestamp is a number. There should be a date format conversion for the mysql timestamp,no?

```
date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime($program->start_time))
```

the date function takes a timestamp long datatype but mysql stores timestamps in a datetime string format. Is there another way to do this where I just convert once?

Comment: yeah, store the date as a timestamp to begin with

Comment: I have stored it as a timestamp. The timestamp format is a string in mysql is it not? But php date() expects timestamp to be a number.

Comment: if you stored it as a timestamp and you pulled it out as a timestamp and then tried to make a timestamp from a timestamp the strtotime function will return false and the date() function won't work..

Comment: if it's a number that was converted to a string by mysql and pulled out as a string, just typecast the timestamp string when you go to use it like so `date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime((int)$program->start_time))`

Comment: I have clarified my question. My code works I am asking if there is a way that can do it without converting the datatype because it seems to me like there must be but I haven't found it so maybe I did something wrong elsewhere that makes this work.

Comment: @iamde_coder I think Phil thought you were referring to the [MySQL Timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) type, not a numeric unix timestamp.

Comment: `the mysql timestamp datatype is a string` - this is false.  The mysql timestamp is an integer field which is automatically converted to date string when queried.  You can access the integer version via casting or selecting `SELECT my_timestamp+0 AS my_timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need to change the dates in your code.

In `Laravel` base Model, dates works as `Carbon` objects. When that fields are stored in database, they're mutated to database date format. That's because date fields have their owns getter/setters in base model.

You don't need to change your custom date fields formats, only declare them in the `$dates` Model propertie so it can mutate that fields when they are stored in database.

For example, in this User model class the attribute `start_time` will be mutated from Carbon to MySQL format when it will be saved.

```
Class User extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $dates = ['start_time'];
}
```

You can read more about that here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators

I expect that would help you to understand it better.